# Error ORA-01034: Oracle not available

Tags: oracle, novell

I have an old Novell server which runs DocsOpen.
I know very little about this system, basically we had a disk fault which halted the system.
The server was rebooted and came up, I had to manually mount the DATA volume and then reboot again.  All seems to be working but nobody can get in to DocsOpen, getting the error ORA-01034: Oracle not available.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Oracle is not running. Did the server survive reboots in the past? The reason I ask is that the commands to load Oracle may appear in AUTOEXEC.NCF, which is executed automatically each time the server is restarted, or may be entered from the server console manually each time after the restart.

This file is located in SYS:\SYSTEM, you can view it from a workstation connected to the server, provided you have enough rights to do so, or you can run EDIT from the server console and navigate from its file selection menus to the file.

To exit EDIT.NLM, press Esc

Comment: I have already found the command in the autoexec.ncf and I commented it out so I can run it manually.  
When it was starting in the autoexec.ncf it started the manager and then stopped (or just dissapeared) - didn't look like there was any errors.

Comment: Try to repair the DATA volume. Depending on the version of NetWare you're using and the filesystem on the DATA volume, you'll either need to dismount the volume first with DISMOUNT command, run VREPAIR and follow the menus, or use NSS /POOLVERIFY command and select the volume from the list. Either way, you'll need to mount the volume with MOUNT command after repairing it. You probably can determine what way to use by running VOLUMES command and checking the file system type of the volume in the last column titled Flags. If it shows NSS, select the second way. Good luck :-)